# How do i change the legend label on ggplot, geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

[image]I am unable to change the labels of my ggplot + geom_point. I have tried multiple scale_shape_xxx/ scale_fill_xxx but to no avail. I would like to change the labels to 'n = 20' and 'n =50'.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(m_index, data_frame_20, data_frame_50) 
df_long <- gather(df, legend, value, -m_index)
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = m_index, y = value, colour = legend)) + geom_point() + 
labs(x = "Values of m", y = " Probability of Maximum Absolute Correlation ", 
     title = "Dot plot of probability") +
scale_shape_manual(name = 'Legend', labels = c('n = 20', 'n = 50'))
```

Comment: Try `scale_colour_manual()` instead

Comment: use `+ scale_color_hue(labels=c("n=20", "n=50"))`

Comment: Wow thank you so much! it worked :)